# Node.Js Express GET Request with Params | ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, get

I have a basic html5 player on the client side. And i'm making get request for specific video with parameters. I tried it on empty project it was working well. Then i copy that get request to my actual project and it's giving me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. I'm stuck and i really need help.

Here my get method :

```
    // Send Video to HTML5 player
    app.get('/api/video/:folder' , function(req, res) {
      var folder = req.params.folder;
      const path = 'D:/VideoClips/' + folder + '/clip.mp4';
      const stat = fs.statSync(path);
      const fileSize = stat.size;
      const range = req.headers.range;

      if (range) {
        const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
        const end = parts[1]
          ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
          : fileSize-1;

        const chunksize = (end-start)+1;
        const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end});
        const head = {
          'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
          'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
          'Content-Length': chunksize,
          'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }

        res.writeHead(206, head);
        file.pipe(res);
      } else {
        const head = {
          'Content-Length': fileSize,
          'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
        }
        res.writeHead(200, head);
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
      }
    });
```

I'm just changing html5 player's src with javascript. When it's changed it's making get request to server :

```
var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
player.src = 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4000/api/video/' + folder;
```

I couldn't find any reason for refused connection. Error log from chrome develoer :

```
GET http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4000/api/video/testfolder_30 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Can you make any successful requests to `http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4000`?  The first thing to figure out is if this issue is specific to the particular request or if it's happening to all requests to this server.  Anything showing in the browser console?  Could this be a CORS issue?

Comment: Can you ping that host from the client computer?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have other post methods. They are working perfectly. And i pinged the host successfully. For ex. i have one post method which it's sending the date to the server and server list files for that day and sending the list to client. It's working perfectly. Just this get method doesn't work

Comment: From what I see, there's a high chance that your server process can't access a path outside of its own context (i.e. `D:/VideoClips/...`) and your server is probably crashing because of it, giving the connection refused error. I would try moving the video to a path within your project to ensure the user that runs the server process has access to it and if that fails, wrap everything in a try/catch block and log the error in the catch to get more info.

Comment: @ruedamanuel I copy one of my folder to app's path and i changed path variable to `const path = __dirname + folder + '/clip.mp4';` It's still giving me the same error. Connection Refused. And try catch block doesn't give me any error to log. And top of my function i put this code `console.log(req.params.folder);` it's not giving me any log it's weird.